# Problem aligning the canvas to the right in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, flex3

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute">
    <mx:Canvas width="100%" height="100%">
        <mx:Canvas backgroundColor="#A8A8A8" height="100%"  right="0" top="0" width="100">

        </mx:Canvas>
    </mx:Canvas>
    <mx:VBox width="800" height="100%" >

    </mx:VBox>
</mx:Application>
```

My code above works absolutely fine, until i resize my browser window to a size below 800px width.

When the browser window is make of lesser width than 800px, the canvas with background color #A8A8A8 is on the right of the window, but the problem is, when I move the scroll bar, the canvas should remain on the right of the window. Which does not happen, and that is what my problem is.

How can I solve this issue. What should I do to keep my canvas be on the right=0 all the time.

Plz help me.

Regards
Zeeshan

Answer (score 0):

Your canvas get scrolled with the application. It keeps right="0", but right border is shifted off screen. You can disable scrolling with `<mx:Application horizontalScrollPolicy="off">` and VBox below should not have fixed width of 800.

Comment: also make your vbox minWidth= 800

Comment: No i am sorry, this is not what i can do, I can not make horizontalScrollPolicy off.

Comment: So your application itself needs to scroll, and some containers in it must not scroll with it? This is possible only if you will update their positions on the fly. But this is complex task. Much better if you can separate scrollable part from application container.